# Display last 7 days data based on date selected in the filter - Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am creating a dashboard that shows the last 7 days of data as shown below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmSLS.png

However, if the user filters for a specific date lets say March 6, I need to show data for the previous 7 days starting Mar 6 (Feb 28  - Mar 6). How could I get this built in a Tableau dashboard to have the last 7 days change dynamically depending on the user actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **parameter** for dates. Select data type *date*, allowable values *list*, and add it from your date field. Right click on this parameter, and select *Show parameter control* option.

Then, generate a boolean calculated field using this parameter, something like:

```
DATEDIFF('day',[Your Date Field],[Date Parameter])<7
AND DATEDIFF('day',[Your Date Field],[Date Parameter])>=0
```

Drag this field to filters, and select only *True* values.

Comment: Hi,I am trying to build a dashboard that would display the last 7 days actual count along with the average of previous 4 weekdays. I have the average of previous 4 weekdays as a calculation but when I add the filter to only show last 7 days, the average of previous 4 weekdays becomes zero but if I increase the timeline to more than 28 days(say 29 days) then I see value for the 29th day. Any help would be much appreciated. 
[View when only last 7 days is filtered][1]
[View when 29 days is filtered][2]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjWud.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHzOG.png